# Posting a JSON string with multiple values to ext js panel

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs

I am working on an element of an application I am developing. I have a small web app dedicated to keep track of clients for a business. Currently my capability is pretty limited. I store the note along with other attributes in the clients table. I decided to try and make it a bit better by adding a note table and updating an ext js panel with the notes.

Everything works if I only have one note in my notes query.

Otherwise I receive this error.

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id
..._date":"2013-10-08","note_body":"abcd"},{"username":"rcox","bdev_firstname":"Tre...
```

This is the PHP I am using.

```
case 'note':
$userid = $_REQUEST['clientID'];
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT a.username, b.bdev_firstname, b.bdev_lastname, n.note_date, n.note_body FROM admin a, bdevs b, clients c, notes n WHERE  c.clientID=".$userid.";");
$query->execute();
while($cli = $query->fetch()) {
$json = '{"username":"'.$cli['username'].'","bdev_firstname":"'.$cli['bdev_firstname'].'","bdev_lastname":"'.$cli['bdev_lastname'].'","note_date":"'.$cli['note_date'].'","note_body":"'.$cli['note_body'].'"},';   
$note .= $json;
}
$note = trim($note, ',');
echo '{success: true, data:'.$note.'}';   
break;
```

This is my ext js function.

```
function getNote(){
    var selectedNote = userGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'inc/template.php',
        params: {list: 'note',
                clientID: selectedNote.get('clientID')
                },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(f,a){
            var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(f.responseText);

                if(jsonData.success == true)
                {
                    var username = jsonData.data.username;
                    var bdev_firstname = jsonData.data.bdev_firstname;
                    var bdev_lastname = jsonData.data.bdev_lastname;
                    var note_date = jsonData.data.note_date;
                    var note_body = jsonData.data.note_body;
                    RightPanel.update('<b>Admin:</b> ' + username + '<br/><b>Buissiness Dev Rep:</b> ' + bdev_firstname + bdev_lastname + '<br/><b>Note Date:</b> ' + note_date + ' <br/>----------<br/> ' + note_body);
                }
                else
                {
                    RightPanel.update('Access Denied');
                }
        },
        failure: function(f,a){
            Ext.Msg.alert("Error", "Access Denied");
        }
    });
}
```

> This has been answered below. For more troubleshooting on this topic you can visit my question on Sencha Forums. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273478-MOVED-POST-Posting-a-JSON-array-with-multiple-values-to-ext-js-panel&p=1002545#post1002545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point of using json if you actually don't use it.

```
case 'note':
$userid = $_REQUEST['clientID'];
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT a.username, b.bdev_firstname, b.bdev_lastname, n.note_date, n.note_body FROM admin a, bdevs b, clients c, notes n WHERE  c.clientID = ?");
$query->execute(array($userid));
$response = json_encode(array('success'=> true, data => $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));
echo $response;   
break;
```

And then ext.js part where your error lies - if data is an array, you need to iterate over it, before you can access associative fields, right?

```
            if(jsonData.success == true)
            {
                var i, item;
                for(  i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++; ) {
                item = jsonData.data[i];                    
                RightPanel.update('<b>Admin:</b> ' + item.username + '<br/><b>Buissiness Dev Rep:</b> ' + item.bdev_firstname+" "+item.bdev_lastname + '<br/><b>Note Date:</b> ' + item.note_date + ' <br/>----------<br/> ' + item.note_body);
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not an extremely experience programmer, I had tried to iterate through the array but I couldn't get it right. I see now I made some pretty stupid mistakes. I really appreciate your answer and I'm giving it a try right now. Thanks again!

Comment: making some edits - for example, i forgot that `execute` requires array as a parameter. But anyways, if you're using php with any js framework do remember - you have `json_encode` to do the job for you, so don't prepare all the arrays by yourself. P. S. If an answer is useful, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: Of course, of course! 

I would welcome the edits though. I'm running into some problems. For instance I am receiving "SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer" for an unknown reason. I have added the semi-colon. weird. ANYWAY, thanks!

Comment: Also, json_encode was a god send. I learned to prepare it that way in school so I've been using that method for a year or so, I haven't had much need for it so that old code is what I jumped on when I started working on this project.

Comment: Just to note to initiation of the for loop should have semi-colons. 
`for(i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++)`

Ha, you answered before I could finish my comment.

Comment: There is one small error in the $response variable. data needs to be 'data'
`$response = json_encode(array('success'=> true, 'data' => $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)));`

Now it is sort of working. I get this response 

`{"success":true,"data":[{"username":"rcox","bdev_firstname":"T***","bdev_lastname":"****","note_date":"2013-10-08","note_body":"abcd"},{"username":"rcox","bdev_firstname":"T***","bdev_lastname":"****","note_date":"2013-10-01","note_body":"qwerrtyer"}]}`

But this is what my panel prints. 

`Admin: rcox
Buissiness Dev Rep: T******
Note Date: 2013-10-01
----------
qwerrtyer`

Comment: This is what the print should look like. I can't figure out why it is only giving me one of the responses (the last one at that, figure it would be the first.)

`Admin: rcox
Buissiness Dev Rep: T******
Note Date: 2013-10-01
----------
qwerrtyer

Admin: rcox
Buissiness Dev Rep: T******
Note Date: 2013-10-01
----------
qwerrtyer`